# Magento 2 Module Development Workflow

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, development, workflow

What is the most Optimal Development Workflow using Magento 2.3.5 in 2020?

I've got a Task to create Magento 2 Module.

When i upload the written code to server the page doesn't update the code (CSS for Example).

I've tried:

- disabling Cache
- using Cache/Flush
- changing to Developer Mode
- removing generated code

The only way for the Page to take my changes is:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento index:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

The Problem is that this way of doing things takes a lot of time.

There must be a better Way of doing this, but i couldn't find the right solution for it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to deploy the module, then it will accept your changes.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya What do you mean by Deploy the module?

I've enabled the Module already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to develop new module for Magento 2, it's recomended to switch to Developer mode (`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`).
And I recommend you to enable all magento cache, because it can take too much time to load, if you doesn't.

To see your less/css changes your should clean static files (`rm -rf pub/static var/view_preprocessed`) and load page with `disable cache` browser option.

If you want to see your DI changes (changes in di.xml files), you should flash di cache (`rm -rf generated/metadata/ && rm -rf generated/code/`)

If you want to see all other changes on the frontend, you need to flush specific magento cache (or all cache). Command: `php bin/magento cache:flush`

If you created new magento module (required files: registration.php and etc/module.xml), you should run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to register module in the system (list of registered modules - app/etc/config.php)

When you deploy the website to live environment, you should switch your magento to production mode (`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`) and run following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile // to update di changes
php setup:static-content:deploy // to update static files
```